# Buscar em duas tabelas MySQL

Tags: mysql, sql

É possível dar uma "select" mesclando duas tabelas no MySQL? por exemplo:
tenho uma tabela chamada **"favoritos"** que salva o ***id_da_postagem*** e o ***id_do_usuario***. a ideia seria percorrer a tabela **favoritos** mesclada com a tabela **postagens**, (onde estão salvo título,conteúdo e etc do post propriamente dito), e selecionar todas essas postagens de acordo com o **id_do_usuario** da tabela **favoritos**?

Comment: Relacionada: [Qual é a diferença entre INNER JOIN e OUTER JOIN?](http://pt.stackoverflow.com/q/6441/18246)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Tem sim. Isso se chama `Join`. Há vários tipos de join's possíveis, mas não vou focar nisso porque já temos [essa pergunta](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/q/6441/18246) que trata muito bem do assunto.

No seu caso é bem simples, veja no exemplo. Eu fiz um Inner Join da tabela `Favoritos` com a tabela `Postagens` sempre que o campo `Id` da tabela `Postagens` for igual ao campo `Id_da_Postagem` na tabela `Favoritos`.

```sql
Select Post.Id, Post.Descricao, Post.Etc --Colunas que quero retornar/mostrar
From Favoritos Fav -- Tabela principal
Inner Join Postagens Post On Post.Id = Fav.Id_da_Postagem And Fav.Id_do_Usuario = 850; -- Condição (850 é só um Id de exemplo)
```

Comment: Obrigado, era isso que tava procurando , só que parece que ele está puxando postagens mais de uma vez.

Comment: Ahh, realmente isso pode acontecer. É melhor deixar a condição do usuário dentro do Join. Isso vai fazer com que apenas as postagens do usuário determinado sejam retornadas. Editei a resposta.

Comment: Você não alterou a ordem do from e do inner join, né?

Comment: Cara, perdão rs, foi um erro meu mesmo de sintaxe, já está funcionando, obrigado mesmo!